# Unhandled SoapException because of missing element

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

unfortunately a not too easy to answer question, as I cannot really provide you with the correpsonding WSDL. But maybe you can help me anyways.

Setting: I have a C#.Net 4 application communicating to a SOAP webservice via a class, generated by wsdl.exe.

```
        ZWmGetEpc storage = new ZWmGetEpc();

        storage.IpLgnum = "XYZ";

        Z_WM_GET_EPC erpInventory = new Z_WM_GET_EPC();

        ZWmGetEpcResponse response = erpInventory.ZWmGetEpc(storage);
```

So far, so good. But when I start the program, I get an error on `erpInventory.ZWmGetEpc(storage)`, namely an unhandled SoapException:

```
CX_ST_MATCH_ELEMENT:.System expected element 'IpLgnum'
```

But in the debug console I can clearly see that the object `storage` has an element `IpLgnum`, which is `"XYZ"` just as it should be.

Any ideas?

Comment: `CX_ST_MATCH_ELEMENT` is not a message from the ASMX framework. It must be a message from the service itself.

Comment: Okay thanks, so my question was not sufficient. I will post a different one, focusing on the exchanged SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John points out, the error message is from the web service itself. My question therefore cannot be answered just like that.